# What are the tighest lower bound in a 2-D Peak Finding?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, lower-bound

I would like to know the lower bound for time complexity in algorithms that need to find just one peak in a 2D array, and in general in a N-D array. The best for 2-D I achieved was O(n)

Comment: Can you define peak finding? Does [1,1,1] have 0, 1 or 3 peaks?

Comment: My definition is: " It is higher, or equal ,than its neighbors". In this case of yours should be 3 peaks, but just finding anyone is ok

Answer (score 0):

For an N x M array, consider the following algorithm:

We take the middle row, and in O(M) find the maximum element. If both of its (columnwise) neighbors are not larger, it is a peak. Otherwise, if the above number is larger, one of the top half of the rows must contain a peak. Similarly of course for the bottom half.

Thus, we can divide the search space in half with an O(M) step, leading to a total runtime of O(M log N). I do believe this is optimal, but have not proven it so.